# CSS sprite background does not shift

Tags: css, background, sprite

I have become increasing frustrated with what should be fairly simple CSS sprite code.  I have been working on a map of counties that enlarges the county name when the mouse hovers over the link box which is a little bit bigger than the size of the county name.

Here is my html code for two counties (there are several more counties in my original code)...

```
<ul id="counties">

<li id="russell"><a href="index.html">Russell</a></li>
<li id="smyth"><a href="index.html">Smyth</a></li>

</ul>
```

...and here is my CSS code...

```
#counties {
background: url(./LINKS/counties_hover_map.png) no-repeat;
width: 750px;
height: 648px;
position: relative;
}
#counties li {list-style: none; display: block; position: absolute;}
#counties a {display: block; text-indent: -9999px; text-decoration: none;}

#russell {left: 244px; top: 112px; width: 161px; height: 56px;}
#russell a {height: 56px; border: none; outline: none;}
#russell a:hover{background-position: 0px -680px;}

#smyth {left: 510px; top: 164px; width: 144px; height: 56px;}
#smyth a {height: 56px; border: none; outline: none;}
#smyth a:hover {background-position: 0px -784px;}
```

...any insights would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: You have no background defined for #russell or #smith so there's nothing to move.

Comment: Can you share the site or fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

remove 
background: url(./LINKS/counties_hover_map.png) no-repeat; 
from ##counties,

add that line to #counties a instead.

so it becomes:

```
    #counties {
    width: 750px;
    height: 648px;
    position: relative;
    }
    #counties li {list-style: none; display: block; position: absolute;}
    #counties a {
    display: block; text-indent: -9999px; text-decoration: none;
background: url(./LINKS/counties_hover_map.png) no-repeat;
}

    #russell {left: 244px; top: 112px; width: 161px; height: 56px;}
    #russell a {height: 56px; border: none; outline: none;}
    #russell a:hover{background-position: 0px -680px;}

    #smyth {left: 510px; top: 164px; width: 144px; height: 56px;}
    #smyth a {height: 56px; border: none; outline: none;}
    #smyth a:hover {background-position: 0px -784px;}
```